# How to embed contents of an excel worksheet into a email in javamail?

Tags: java, excel, jakarta-mail, apache-poi

I need help to send an email using javamail-api and embed the content of an excel sheet in it before sending.

Comment: you need to attach the excel file to the email or to extract content of this file and put it directly in the mail ?

Comment: I need to extract the content and put it directly in mail. Only the non-empty cells. Thanks a lot for reply.

Comment: What format do you want to get the contents in to put in the mail body? HTML? CSV? Plain Text? One big splurge with no formatting or care for order?

Comment: Actually I have to send a neatly formatted table in mail.So I tried to embed HTML code in mail but it doesn't look any good. I saw a mail which contains a small table embedded in it, and it looked like that in an excel-sheet. I know that we can copy paste part of excel sheet in mail manually but I want to do the same through java program.So my question is how to embed excel(csv,xls or any format) in javamail.

Comment: May I suggest to update your question with the details you gave in the comments?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure but i guess [this](http://code.geekinterview.com/java/read-excel-file-data-java-code.html) might help you.
As you can first read the data and then put them in mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround it by creating your HTML-mail template via an external graphical HTML editor.
Once the template is ready, just load the template to your JAVA app and edit it to add the required data.
I find [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to do great job with reading from XLS\XLSX files.